# how to get the correct surface plot with matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, figure

I want to plot three things, alpha, temp and Ea. all of them of same length i.e. 81 this the code i use for this.

```
clear all
clc
alp=[xlsread('3ddata.xlsx','Sheet1','A:A')]
temp=[xlsread('3ddata.xlsx','Sheet1','B:B')];
Ea=[xlsread('3ddata.xlsx','Sheet1','C:C')];
surf([alp, temp,Ea])
axis tight
xlabel 'Alpha'
ylabel 'temp'
zlabel 'Ea'
```

when i get the plot the x-axis is labelled from 1 to 3 while actually it is from 0.1 to 0.9 (data) and similarly the y-axis is showed to be 1 to 80 on graph while actually it is from 374 to 394 and the same with z-axis (Ea) which is shown on graph from -600 to 200 while actually it is from -619 to -591 .. (alpha from 0.1 to 0.9 , temp from 374 to 394 and Ea from -619 to -591)

the graph is attached here 
http://s27.postimg.org/eiv71pftf/myplot.jpg

Comment: Which variable do you want to plot as a function of the others? Which are the exact sizes of all variables?

Comment: i want to plot Ea as a function of temp and alp. for your information kindly look at the following figure. http://s24.postimg.org/4tsy8ahk5/sample.png

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/4tsy8ahk5/sample.png this is a sample figure of what i want to get and here is my input data http://pastebin.com/TySjCwuc

Answer (score 1):

The way you use `surf` does not really make sense. With one input argument, the whole matrix is a height map. Without having your data, I can only guess: Try `plot3(alp, temp,Ea)`. Does this provide the right output, only missing the surface in between?

You may also try:

```
tri = delaunay(alp,temp);
trisurf(tri,alp,temp,Ea)
```

Can you provide the input data?

Comment: Thanks alot 

The input data is the following 
alp Temp Ea
0.1 391.58 -618.689
0.2 390.802 -514.175
0.3 389.908 -440.807
0.4 388.939 -389.19
0.5 387.836 -351.683
0.6 386.432 -329.766
0.7 384.461 -334.504
0.8 381.028 -382.355
0.9 374.102 -594.966

Shoud i sent you the excel file or screen shoot.

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/4tsy8ahk5/sample.png this is a sample figure of what i want to get and here is my input data http://pastebin.com/TySjCwuc

Comment: Your data describes a line in the 3D-Space, but nut a surface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to plot `Ea` (z axis) as a function of `alp` (x axis) and `temp` (y axis), try

```
surf(alp, temp, Ea)
```

For this to work, the sizes would have to be something like: `alp` 81 x 1; `temp` 81 x 1; `Ea` 81 x 81 (giving the value for each combination of `alp` and `temp`).

Comment: I doubt that `[xlsread('3ddata.xlsx','Sheet1','C:C')]` returns a matrix.

Comment: @DanielR You're right. If all of them are vectors, `plot3` is probably the way to go.

Comment: @LuisMendo when i use

    surf(alp,temp,Ea)

i get the following error 

    Error using surf (line 75)
    Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector.

Comment: http://s24.postimg.org/4tsy8ahk5/sample.png this is a sample figure of what i want to get and here is my input data http://pastebin.com/TySjCwuc